# Which Linux distro is most popular these days?

Tags: linux

I was wondering if you could tell me that which is the most famous LINUX operating system these days?

Comment: In terms of what? How many installations? Number of published news articles about them? Number of books about them? Amount of traffic to the download servers?

Comment: Note that Android is a Linux distribution.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question, but I think it's impossible to answer in its current form. "most popular" or "most famous" cannot be measured. If you edit your question to ask about measurable statistics, your question will become valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity

Answer (score 0):

According to [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) the **Mint** distro is currently one of the most popular distro today. But since Mint and many other distro´s is built from Ubuntu, maybe the correct answer should be **Ubuntu**

In [ZDNet´s](http://www.zdnet.com/the-5-most-popular-linux-distributions-7000003183/) ranking the Mint distro is also in the top, by the way.

The best thing you could do is to try them yourself and see what they will go for.

Comment: That's statistics of access to the DistroWatch website, not of the popularity of the distributions themselves.